# Subclass for Superclass with @dynamic @properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, dynamic

I'm using [PAPreferences](https://github.com/dhennessy/PAPreferences) to manage app specific preferences/defaults. It's basically a layer on top of `NSUserDefaults` that lets me read/write data to NSUserDefaults as if I was just using a normal class.

The basic setup is to subclass PAPreferences, add `@properties` in your subclass' .h file, **and declare them as `@dynamic` in the .m file**.

The class hierarchy looks like this:

```
- PAPreferences
    - MyPreferences // all @properties defined here, and set in -init
```

My project builds many different targets, and each time I add a new target, I have to duplicate the previous `MyPreferences` file. A lot of code is duplicated, and each time I want to make a change to my app's preferences, I have to do so in many different files.

I'd like to create a class hierarchy like so:

```
- PAPreferences
    - MyPreferencesBase // all @properties defined here
        - MyPreferences // all @properties set in -init
```

With the previous class hierarchy, my app is crashing when `MyPreferenes#init` is run and I set the first instance variable  (unrecognized selector sent to instance).

How can I write a subclass for a superclass whose @properties are set to be @dyanmic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not general to a superclass which implements properties dynamically. It's specific to the implementation of `PAPreferences`.

In [`-[PAPreferences init]`](https://github.com/dhennessy/PAPreferences/blob/master/PAPreferences/PAPreferences.m#L183), it examines the current class's properties by using the runtime function [`class_copyPropertyList()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/class_copyPropertyList). That function is documented to only return the properties declared in that class, not its superclass(es). As a consequence, `PAPreferences` is blind to the dynamic properties of the superclass.

`[PAPreferences init]` would need to walk up the chain of superclasses, processing the properties of all of the classes. It would stop when it reached itself. It might also need to adjust which class it adds a method to in `+resolveInstanceMethod:`.

Comment: ok, that's good to know. before posting this though, I created a demo project with three classes to mimic the class hierarchy I was going for in my question (SuperClassA, SuperClassB (with property declared), and SubClass). If I let everything synthesize as normal, I have no problem accessing SuperClassB's property when instantiating SubClass. However, if I make SuperClassB's property dynamic, my test app crashes with the same error as it was in my real project. That's why I thought it had something to do with the property being dynamic.

Comment: Did you actually put in an infrastructure to dynamically provide the property's accessors? If a property is declared `@dynamic`, the compiler doesn't generate any accessor methods. If you do nothing to compensate for that fact, attempting to access the property will crash. Has nothing to do with super- or sub-classes. `PAPreferences` will generate accessors for the properties it knows about on the fly. That's what prevents crashes in the normal case. However, it doesn't do that for properties declared on superclasses, which leaves a hole and the crash remains.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for your thorough explanation.